# jQuery set bgcolor of inner div

Tags: jquery

I have a div structure & I want to change bg color to white of `<div>HERE</div>`
& i can not set id for this div.

```
<div class="graph-wp">
    <div id="placeholder">
        <div class="tickLabels">
            <div class="legend">
                <div>HERE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.legend').css({'background-color': '#FFFFFF'});
});
```

but failed

Comment: why not use class selector or child selector?

Comment: based on which condition? Just setting the background-color for `.legend` won't be sufficient?

Comment: Maybe you are loading the `div.legend` after the page is loaded? through ajax or something?

Comment: If you are using JSFiddle to output these, make sure you you have the first dropdown to no wrap (head) and not onLoad. http://jsfiddle.net/sircapsalot/VugpJ/

Comment: `$('div.legend > div').css({'background-color': '#fff'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I used:

```
$(".legend").children().css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` selector:

```
$('.legend').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

To add the css to the inner div you can use:

```
$('.legend div').first().css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

This will ensure that only the first div will take the `background-color`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#placeholder .legend").css('background-color', 'white');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, please make sure that you inclued all nessecery js files.

And note, that your div is empty and in this case you will not see apllaying of styles

`#FFFFFF` this is WHITE color, so your div should be placed on div with another color in order to see affect

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CSS for this -

```
.inner > div {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Otherwise if you need to use jQuery -

```
$('.inner > div').css("background-color", "#FFF");
```